# Manipulating data in SQL Lite db

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to SQL Lite db manipulation.

I wrote a DB handling class from this tutorial [SQL Lite tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PersonalAssistant";

// TASKS table name
private static final String TABLE_TASKS = "TASKS";

// Tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String UUID = "uuid";
private static final String ACTION = "action";
private static final String TIME = "time";
private static final String DAY = "day";
private static final String RECEPIENTS = "receipients";
private static final String BODY = "body";
private static final String SUBJECT = "subject";
private static final String STATUS = "status";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +UUID + " TEXT,"+ ACTION + " TEXT,"
            + TIME + " TEXT," + DAY + " TEXT," + RECEPIENTS+  " TEXT," +BODY + " TEXT," + " TEXT," +SUBJECT + " TEXT,"  +SUBJECT + " TEXT," +")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
// add task to table
public void addTask(Task task) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ACTION, task.getAction());

    values.put(UUID, task.getUuid());

    values.put(TIME, task.getTime());
    values.put(DAY, task.getDay());
    values.put(RECEPIENTS, task.getReceipients());
    values.put(BODY, task.getBody());
    values.put(SUBJECT, task.getSubject());
    values.put(STATUS, task.getStatus());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}        .............
```

My question is how do i call this class for db manipulation from my application activities?

How do i instatiate my class from other activities which are not extending SQLiteOpenHelper?

I can define the class and methods as static but is it a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so just by instantiating object from your `DatabaseHandler` class like this:

```
DabataseHandler dbHandler;
dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

And then you can use methods in your `Databasehandler` class using `dbHandler`.

For example:

```
Task myTask = new Task();
dbHandler.addTask(myTask);
```

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use a Singleton pattern to access the Sqlite DB from all the different activities.

My own accepted answer to the question below describe the approach providing code as well:

[How can I access my SQLite Database in a static way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806805/how-can-i-access-my-sqlite-database-in-a-static-way/20806911#20806911)